# Increase speed of batch forecast with purrr

Tags: r, forecasting, purrr

I was reading a [blog post](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/batch-forecasting/) on batch forecasting and wanted to increase the speed. I tried using `purrr`, but only reduced the time by less than half. Below is a reproducible example showing the example from Hyndman's blog post and showing a `purrr` alternative. How can I reduce this time?

```
library(forecast)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
#read file
retail <- read.csv("https://robjhyndman.com/data/ausretail.csv",header=FALSE)

# hyndmans loop
retail <- ts(retail[,-1],f=12,s=1982+3/12)
ns <- ncol(retail)
h <- 24
fcast <- matrix(NA,nrow=h,ncol=ns)
system.time(
for(i in 1:ns)
  fcast[,i] <- forecast(retail[,i],h=h)$mean
)

#   user  system elapsed 
#  60.14    0.17   61.72 

# purrr try
system.time(
retail_forecast <- retail %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  map(~ts(.,frequency = 7)) %>% 
  map_dfc(~forecast(.,h=h)$mean))

#   user  system elapsed 
#  32.23    0.03   35.32
```

Comment: Changing the frequency will change the computation time. Smaller frequencies are faster. Make frequency=12, and the purr results are almost identical to a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parallelize `purrr` functions using the [`furrr`](https://davisvaughan.github.io/furrr/) package. Here is an excerpt from the package page

> The goal of `furrr` is to simplify the combination of `purrr`’s family of mapping functions and `future`’s parallel processing capabilities. A new set of `future_map_*()` functions have been defined, and can be used as (hopefully) drop in replacements for the corresponding `map_*()` function.
>
> The code draws heavily from the implementations of `purrr` and `future.apply`

Using `furrr` I was able to reduce the computing time more than 3 times on my Linux machine

```r
library(forecast)
library(tidyverse)

### read file
retail <- read.csv("https://robjhyndman.com/data/ausretail.csv", header = FALSE)
```

#### hyndman's loop

```r
retail <- ts(retail[, -1], f = 12, s = 1982 + 3 / 12)
ns <- ncol(retail)
h <- 24
fcast <- matrix(NA, nrow = h, ncol = ns)
system.time(
  for (i in 1:ns)
    fcast[, i] <- forecast(retail[, i], h = h)$mean
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 50.592   0.016  50.599
#
```

#### purrr try

```r
system.time(
  retail_forecast <- retail %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    map(~ts(., frequency = 12)) %>%
    map_dfc(~ forecast(., h = h)$mean)
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 50.232   0.000  50.224 
#
```

#### furrr try

```r
library(furrr)
#> Loading required package: future
# You set a "plan" for how the code should run. The easiest is `multiprocess`
# On Mac this picks plan(multicore) and on Windows this picks plan(multisession)
plan(multiprocess)

system.time(
  retail_forecast <- retail %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    future_map(~ts(., frequency = 12)) %>%
    future_map_dfc(~ forecast(., h = h)$mean)
)

# user  system elapsed 
# 0.172   0.080  14.702
#
```

Created on 2018-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: purrr is almost identical to using a loop if you use frequency=12 rather than the incorrect frequency=7. furrr is still substantially faster